# Do we have $\varphi(R_u(B))\subset R_u(B')$ or not?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G,G'$ be reductive algebraic groups over $\Bbb C$. Are unipotent elements sent to unipotent elements?

Firstly, if $\varphi:G\to G'$ is an injective morphism of algebraic groups, then such a morphism preserves solvability and connectedness, so it seems that for $B\subset G$ a Borel subgroup then $\varphi(B)\subset B'$ for some Borel subgroup $B'\subset G'$.

My question is if $\varphi(R_u(B))\subset R_u(B')$ or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any morphism $f: G \rightarrow G'$ of algebraic groups (not just between reductive algebraic groups) preserves the Jordan decomposition, hence $f$ sends unipotent elements to unipotent elements. A proof can be found in any basic text on algebraic groups.

In any case, in your situation it follows then that $\varphi(R_u(B')) \subseteq \varphi(R_u(B))$.

Comment: Is everything else I have written also true? That was a secondary implicit question in some sense :P.

Comment: Although the standard argument requires us to be in $\text{GL}(V)$. So I suppose implicitly we must take our reductive algebraic groups, and embed them into some $\text{GL}_n$ and $\text{GL}_m$ and use this there.

Comment: Yes, what you said about Borel subgroups is correct. About the Jordan decomposition of elements of $G$, this is independent of the embedding of $G$ into $GL(V)$.  So any element $g \in G$ can be written uniquely as $g = su = us$ with $s$ semisimple, $u$ unipotent. Then in any embedding $G < GL(V)$ we have $s$ semisimple in $GL(V)$ and $u$ unipotent in $GL(V)$